# How can I make all child divs respect parent's fixed size?

Tags: html, css

This has been pestering me like a plague since I found out that the child will absolutely not respect parent's fixed size.

```
#parent{
height: 100%;
max-height: 100%;
min-height: 100%;
width: 100%;
max-width: 100%;
min-width: 100%;
}

#child{
height:100%;
width: 100%;
border: 1px solid black;
}
```

It is really annoying that I have to use `calc(100% - 2px)` just to include the border's size so that it would actually fit in its parent. On every child.

So my question is, is there a workaround with this or do I just have to keep using `calc` on every single (note I have 10 - 21 children in one div) one of em? But what i'm mainly needing is a code that'll force all children inside the parent to respect its size.

Comment: Can you share the part of your html code too, to make it clearer?

Comment: Please understand that i am not using Veiwport. Because by this point i already know how to do that. And @Sim, it's as simple as it can get bro. children inside parent. That's it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

use `box-sizing: border-box` on the child. This includes the border in the width/height

Comment: Thanks dude. I had a lot of varying border sizes so yeah... burned my head XD